# Proxy to add CORS headers with netcat

Tags: proxy, http-headers, netcat

I'm looking for a little script using `nc` which will be used to add [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) headers (at least `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`) in order for my local [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) dev application to access a remote webservice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little script inspired by [this blog](http://notes.tweakblogs.net/blog/7955/using-netcat-to-build-a-simple-tcp-proxy-in-linux.html) which I called `cors-http-proxy.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh -e

if [ $# != 3 ]
then
    echo "usage: $0 <src-port> <dst-host> <dst-port>"
    exit 0
fi

while true; do
    TMP=`mktemp -d`
    BACK=$TMP/pipe.back
    SENT=$TMP/pipe.sent
    RCVD=$TMP/pipe.rcvd
    trap 'rm -rf "$TMP"' EXIT
    mkfifo -m 0600 "$BACK" "$SENT" "$RCVD"
    sed 's/^/ => /' <"$SENT" &
    sed 's/^/<=  /' <"$RCVD" &
    nc -l -p "$1" <"$BACK" | sed -u "s/^Host: .*$/Host: $2:$3/" | tee "$SENT" | nc "$2" "$3" | sed -u "/^Date: /a Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" | tee "$RCVD" >"$BACK"
done
```

Comment: Very nice, trying this out right now. 
why did you add the `while true` ?

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work for binary data (file upload), need to find a replacement for sed that can work with binary data...

Comment: It didn't help me eventually (because of binary support), but it is very useful.
I made some adjustments for OSX, you can see it here: https://pastebin.com/4wZutf8h